# Threads Vs Processes Generally

Tags: multithreading, process, threadpool

1) Why is thread creation less expensive than process creation?

2) What is the difference between a thread and a subprocess? How would this relate to the above question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process is created it is allocated heap and stack memory. Threads on the other hand only get a stack and share the heap with the parent process. This means that even if you just consider memory allocation it is more "expensive" to create a process than a thread.

Subprocesses are simply processes that were created by another process. They are otherwise independent and get their own memory space. Here's [an article that goes into some more detail](http://www.differencebetween.net/miscellaneous/difference-between-thread-and-process/).

Comment: but doesn't a child process share it's parents memory?

Comment: Ok, so the only main cost is memory allocation?

Comment: @user559142: The term "subprocess" is a bit misleading. It is simply a process with its own stack and heap memory and possibly threads. A subprocess is a process, period. As far as "main cost" goes: Memory allocation is the biggest difference but there are other, OS-specific differences.

Comment: @Paul is the executable code of a process usually copied into a sub-thread? Isn't this shared as well, where a process will usually make a new copy of the executable code?

Comment: @San Jacinto: Not really. A thread gets its own execution stack. It can use/share its processes' code while it runs but nothing is copied ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is probably very OS dependent but a general rule :

1. Threads of a process live in the same virtual memory space as their parent. So a thread creation is less expensive than a process creation because the underlying operating system doesn't need to create a full virtual memory space.
2. A subprocess is just another process spawned by a parent.

Comment: If the child process is a duplicate of the parent process, does it not share the same virtual memory space?

Comment: The subprocess is just another process that lives in it's own space. :)